# ideviceinstaller fails with ERROR: could not locate iTunesMetadata.plist in archive

Tags: ios

I want to install an ios application with libmobiledevice 
but I got an error after `ideviceinstaller -i xxx.ipa`

`ideviceinfo` and `ideviceinstall -u` still works.

I have macbook pro, in mac mini with the same libmobiledevice I can install it with no error.

The error is:

> Error : Could not locate iTunesMetadata.plist in archive ! Could not
>   determine CFBundleName!

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version of libimobiledevice : http://libiphone.lighthouseapp.com/projects/27916/tickets/298-ideviceinstaller-i-fails-with-could-not-locate-payloadappnameappinfoplist-in-archive